# Evaluate $\int_0^\pi\left(1-\cos\left(2x\right)\right)^\frac{3}{2}\,dx$

Tags: calculus

> Evaluate$$\int_0^\pi(1-\cos2x)^\frac32\,dx$$

I'm doing something wrong, but I don't know what.$$\int_0^\pi(1-\cos2x)(1-\cos2x)^\frac12\,dx$$Substituting $u=1-\cos2x,du=2\sin2x\,dx$ we get$$\int_a^bu\cdot\sqrt u\,du$$where $a=1-\cos(2\cdot0)=0$ and $b=1-\cos(2\cdot\pi)=0$. Because $\int_0^0f(y)\,dy=0$, this means$$\int_0^\pi(1-\cos2x)^\frac32\,dx=\int_0^0u\cdot\sqrt u\,du=0$$which is wrong.

I'd like to find my error and get some hints for a better solution.

**EDIT**

I have a solution, I think.

$$\int (1-\cos 2x)^{(3/2)} dx=\int (2\sin^2x)^{(3/2)}dx$$

And from here it's more or less similar to $\int\sin^3x\,dx$, which using the Pythagorean identity and $u=\cos x$, gives me a good solution.

Bad u-sub in the first attempted solution above.

Comment: Hint: Your substitution is not one-to-one. Since your function is symmetric about $\pi/2$, compute
$$\int_0^\pi(.) = 2 \int_0^{\pi/2}(.)$$

Comment: Use the half-angle formula: $1-\cos{2 x}=2 \sin^2{x}$.

Comment: @gammatester I'm sorry, but your explanation of the substitution not being one-to-one is not clear for me.

Comment: Forget about it, I included it afterwards. The splitting part of the integral remains correct. But check your substitution: $u\cdot\sqrt u\,du$ is not equivalent to $u(x)\cdot\sqrt{u(x)}\,dx$, you missed $u'(x)$.

Comment: @gammatester Oh, okay, I get it. Bad mistake...

Answer (score 1):

Since $\cos(2x)=1-2\sin^2(x)$,
$$
\begin{align}
\int_0^\pi(1-\cos(2x))^{3/2}\,\mathrm{d}x
&=2^{3/2}\int_0^\pi\sin^3(x)\,\mathrm{d}x\\
&=-2^{3/2}\int_0^\pi\sin^2(x)\,\mathrm{d}\cos(x)\\
&=-2^{3/2}\int_0^\pi\left(1-\cos^2(x)\right)\,\mathrm{d}\cos(x)\\
&=-2^{3/2}\left[\cos(x)-\frac13\cos^3(x)\right]_0^\pi\\
&=2^{3/2}\left(2-\frac13\cdot2\right)\\
&=\frac83\sqrt2
\end{align}
$$

Comment: This is what I got as well. Happy to see our answers corroborate.

Comment: I was trying to point out the same thing as gammatester (who commented almost simultaneously), but a bit more explicitly. I hope it was of some help.